# Simultaneous fitting of two function with two data sets with same set of parameters

Tags: fitting

I am trying to fit two functions with two data sets simultaneously and the function is basically the real and imaginary part of the Lorentzian, I have the dataset which you can find in the link here [Dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZtsbYpWuvq85BWGO1XqOS-wimQIgz6I9/view?usp=sharing), it has 3 columns, first is frequency, 2nd is the Real part and the 3rd column is the imaginary part.

I have defined my functions as

```
modelImag = ((a*(f^2 - x^2))/((f^2 - x^2)^2 + (d^2*x^2)));
modelReal = (((a*(d*x))/((f^2 - x^2)^2 + ((d)^2*x^2))));
```

Please not that I can fit the my data indiviudually but the paametess value are different for both case, in practice same set of parmeters should fit both functions.
I have taken my dataset as

```
Data = Import["E:\\Shelender\\codes\\Mathematica\\Q\\a.csv"];
dataReal = Data[[All, {1, 3}]];
dataImag = Data[[All, {1, 2}]];
data = Flatten[{{1, #[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ 
    dataReal, {0, #[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ dataImag}, 1]
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[
   data, {modelReal + modelImag}, {{a, 1.0*10^7}, {f, 10.0*10^6}, {d, 
     33000}}, {a, x}];
```

I think I have some problem while non-linear model fit.

Comment: Have a look at this `ResourceFunction` [`MultiNonlinearModelFit`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MultiNonlinearModelFit)

Comment: Might also try searching for related MSE posts. This topic has come up before.